# Angular seavice getAll is not a function

Tags: angularjs, rest

I've got a function in an Angular controller like so:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var controlledID = 'Clause.Clause';
    angular.module('docapp').controller(controlledID, ['$scope', 'common', 'taskSvc', 'clauseSvc', Clauses]);

    function Clauses($scope, clauseSvc, taskSvc, common) {
        $scope.GetContractMaster = function GetContractMaster() {
            clauseSvc.getAll()
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.ContractMaster.rowData = response.d.results;
                console.log(response.d.results);
            });
        };
        $scope.GetContractMaster();
   };
}
})();
```

My Services

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('docapp');
    app.factory("clauseSvc", ["baseSvc", function (baseService) {
        var listEndPoint = '/_api/web/lists/';
        var getAll = function () {
            var query = listEndPoint + "GetByTitle('CLAUSE_MST')/Items?$select=Title,Title,Desc,nodes/ID&$expand=nodes";
            return baseService.getRequest(query);
        };
        return {
            getAll: getAll
        };
    }]);
})();
```

baseService

```
"use strict";
(function () {
    angular.module("docapp")
        .factory("baseSvc", ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {
            var baseUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
            var getRequest = function (query) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    url: baseUrl + query,
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    }
                })
                    .success(function (result) {
                        deferred.resolve(result);
                    })
                    .error(function (result, status) {
                        deferred.reject(status);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            };

            return {
                getRequest: getRequest

            };
        }]);
})();
```

Getting error

```
[true]  [SYSERR] clauseSvc.getAll is not a function Object {exception:
TypeError: clauseSvc.getAll is not a function
at n.GetContractMaster
```

Need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller is declared as

```
    .controller('$scope', 'common',  'taskSvc', 'clauseSvc', Clauses]);
```

and the function is declared as

```
function Clauses($scope,   clauseSvc, taskSvc,  common)
```

So, the variable `clauseSvc`is in fact the `common` service instance, and the variable `common` is in fact the `clauseSvc` service instance.

Do yourself a favor: avoid that kind of bugs and make your code easier to write and read by just avoiding this array syntax, and using [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to make your code minifiable.